# How create a JUnit test to see if a user's array is correct

Tags: arrays, unit-testing, testing, junit

I have to test user's code. The have to create an array with 4 rows and columns. They must change `new[1][2]` to equal 15. So lets say they created this code or something similar (and possibly wrong):

```
int[][] new = new int[4][4];
new[1][2] = 15;
```

how would I check to see if `new[1][2]` actually equals 15 using Junits Tests?  I have to use Junits Tests!!!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things to test here:

1. Implicitly implied - the array is not null
2. The array's length is 4
3. Each subarray's length is 4 (i.e., it isn't a [jagged-arrays](/questions/tagged/jagged-arrays))
4. The int in position [1][2] is really 15:

```java
@Test
public void testArray() {
    int arr[][] = getUserArraySomehow();
    assertNotNull(arr);
    assertEquals(4, arr.length);
    for (int[] subarr : arr) {
        assertEquals(4, subarr.length);
    }
    assertEquals(15, arr[1][2]);
}
```